# Is using the Whitehouse (or Government property) for an election rally or event legal?

Tags: united-states, election

Whatever about Trump's recent partial use of the White House for what he terms a "peaceful protest" (which is certainly a viewpoint hotly contested by others), this did raise the question for me as to what extent, if any, a POTUS can use Government property, particularly the White House itself, in an election campaign.

I am well out of my depth even researching an answer, so what does US election law and norms say about this ?  Are their historical events that define a precedent related to this ?

I would appreciate if the words "Democrat" and "Republican" did not appear in answers.  This is not about party affiliation, just what's reasonable and allowed by US law and custom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me suggest that this question is best suited for Law S.E. as it relates to the law. .

Comment: @BobE but it's about the law governing political activity, so it would be on topic for both sites.

Comment: @phoog agree, maybe with a slight shift in focus.  Questions on norms, clearly Politics. Question on Laws might tend to Law. This Q asks both.